# How can one plot the precision recall curve in Pyspark from the BinaryClassificationEvaluator obtained metrics?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have seen there are some built-in tools to do this in python such as the `sklearn`'s `precision_recall_curve()` function, but i would like to do this using the `pyspark` API as much as possible. However, i don't see any particular built-in tools to do this in `Spark`.

Since i am using `XGBoost` in `pyspark` to solve a binary classification problem. I'm using the `Spark` `BinaryClassificationEvaluator` class to get some metrics as the AUC and the area under the precision/recall curve.

How could i plot the precision/recall curve using the data that this binary evaluator gives?